# Transition for color does not work

Tags: css

I have this piece of code: (view it in fullscreen)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li {
 padding: 10px 18px;
    float: left;
    transition: color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
li:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='nav'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Projects</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Partners</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hover on the `<li>`, it only changes the background color. The color for the text didn't work. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `li:hover a {color: black;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the color the the `a` selector instead of `li` initially. A simple switch like this should make it work (I included your whole snippet plus my change so that you could see the preview):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li {
 padding: 10px 18px;
    float: left;
    transition: color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
/* This is the changed part */
li:hover {
    background: white;
}
li:hover a {
    color: black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='nav'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Projects</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Partners</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what is `li:hover a` was use for? I just undestand that this choose all `<a>` inside the `<li>`. Thanks

Comment: @AzDeveloper yes! so the `li:hover` is selecting the `li` when it's hovered. the `li:hover a` selects all `a` tags within that `li` *when it's hovering.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to change color to `li:hover > a`

```css
body {font-family: sans-serif}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li {
 padding: 10px 18px;
    float: left;
    transition: color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
li:hover {
    background: white;
}
li:hover a {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='nav'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Projects</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Partners</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase, a has `color:white`. So you can give color a on hover or make a `inherit` and give color to li.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: sans-serif}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li {
 padding: 10px 18px;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
    transition: color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}
li:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='nav'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Projects</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Partners</a></li>
 <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a style to a li tag that changes the background color but not the text color. Marks the selectot to like this -> li a:hover{ color: #000; background:#fff;}

Hope this will solve your issue..

And my suggestion is that give the color name in hex code that's a best practise for giving the style to colors.